# Topic of the week #4 - Contesting

Tags: discussion, topic-of-the-week

Dealing with any contest rules, explanations, etc.

Comment: I've created an actual community event. Sorry this got overlooked!

Comment: Also since it only sort of went live, I think I may extend it to two weeks.